# JavaSct performance and async callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm having a little trouble understanding  asynchronous functions in JavaScript (i have looked at other posts , but no joy)

I know that you are able to create asynchronous functions through the use of 'callbacks'

However, I'm not entirely sure why a callback results in the asynchronous execution of functions.

In the example below BEFORE the getInput() function has finished exeucting   we called and executed the function logstuff() (logstuff is the callback)

Therefore we have completed the functions asynchronously ? Am I correct or have i totally missed the point ?

//========================

```
var allUserData = [];



function logStuff (userData) {
    if ( typeof userData === "string")
    {
        console.log(userData);
    }
    else if ( typeof userData === "object")
    {
        for (var item in userData) {
            console.log(item + ": " + userData[item]);
        }
    }
```

}

```
function getInput (options, callback) {
    allUserData.push (options);
    callback (options);
}


getInput ({name:"Rich", speciality:"JavaScript"}, logStuff);
```

many thanks

Comment: code indentation is not a suggestion.

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous about your code. It is however built in such a way that you could add an asynchronous action to `getInput`, as long as you execute `callback` after the asynchronous action completes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you've totally missed the point.

A callback function involves more than just calling it 'callback'.  You need some sort of structure that handles the scheduling, and that's not present in this code.